# I accidentally deleted Heroku binary and cant reinstall

Tags: heroku

I tried to install heroku because I was getting a legacy error. I went on the heroku site and tried to install it, but I kept getting the legacy warning. So I followed the instructions on the site that said [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw6EV.png).

I think I followed the instructions correctly, and deleted the source file of heroku. I deleted the file named 'Heroku' in /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin, but now when I try to reinstall Heroku, I get this warning:

> Warning: heroku/brew/heroku 6.15.22 is already installed

However, when I type

> heroku -v

I get an error

> bash: /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/heroku: No such file or
>   directory

I tried uninstalling heroku with

> rm -rf ~/.heroku sudo rm

and

> -rf /usr/local/heroku /usr/bin/heroku

but when I tried to reinstall it after doing those commands, I get the same error as before, the 'No such file or directory' one. Can someone help me reinstall heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?